# php://output - Only output part of page and not whole page

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I´m using [Phpspreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to generate Excel files.

I want to output the file directly as a download. So I used the following code:

```
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Xlsx"); //Xls is also possible
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="VIEW-tilbud.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer->save("php://output");
```

But this includes all of the content of the page, so my Excel file is corrupted with strange characters.
I cannot get rid of the extra stuff on the page generated from a CMS system, so I won´t be able to just only have the code neede to export the Excel file.

How can I make the code only export a specific part of the page?

Comment: Probably could clear the output buffer before sending your headers & content then `exit` after `$writer->save()`

Comment: Ahh. I will try that. Thanks @Reed!

Comment: Yes!!!! Worked. thanks :) Can you make this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear the output buffer to stop anything already `echo`d. Then `exit` the script after you deliver your content.

```php
//protect against infinite looping, in case of an error with ob_end_clean()
$successfulClean = TRUE;
//empty the output buffer
while (ob_get_level()!==0
       &&$successfulClean===TRUE){
    $successfulClean = ob_end_clean();
}

// your code
$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, "Xlsx"); //Xls is also possible
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="VIEW-tilbud.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer->save("php://output");
//------

//end the request, to stop your CMS from mucking things up. Content Mucking System lol
exit;
```

Relevant Docs:

- [`ob_end_clean()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php)
- [`ob_get_level()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-level.php)
- [`exit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)